# Firebase StorageReference.getFile is not working - FirebaseStorage Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a file in my AsyncTask from Firebase Storage as below:

```
static class DownloadFileFromFireBase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    File file;
    String fileName;
    boolean downloadStatus = false;
    public DownloadFileFromFireBase(Context context,String fileName, File file){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.file = file;
    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference dataRef = storageRef.child(fileName);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataRef.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG,"File Downloaded");
                downloadStatus = true;
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG,"File Download Failed");
                downloadStatus = false;
            }
        });
        return downloadStatus;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream contentsInputStream) {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

**My program neither goes into addOnSuccessListener nor in addOnFailureListener listners (no logs printed in Logcat)**

I have temporarily set my Firebase rules as below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read: if request.auth == null;
        }   
    } 
}
```

I am calling my AsyncTask as below:

```
boolean status = new DownloadFileFromFireBase(getContext(), contentsJsonFile).execute("").get();
```

My files stored on the Firebase storage are accessible from web browser (where I am not logged in/an incognito mode).
My Emulator and Device are using latest Google Services.
Even Firebase Storage API implemented in my project is the latest one (19.1.1).

I am not sure what is going wrong in here. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseStorage Android SDK `getFile(file)` seems no longer work properly in Android Q (SDK 29) which is a breaking changes. You may use `getBytes(file_size)` like this.

```
    //Member variable but depending on your scope
private ByteArrayInputStream inputStream;
private Uri downloadedFileUri;
private OutputStream stream;

//Creating a reference to the link
    StorageReference httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(downloadURL);

    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String type = "";
    String mime = "";
    String folderName = "";

    if (downloadURL.contains("jpg") || downloadURL.contains("jpeg")
            || downloadURL.contains("png") || downloadURL.contains("webp")
            || downloadURL.contains("tiff") || downloadURL.contains("tif")) {
        type = ".jpg";
        mime = "image/*";
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        folderName = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
    }
    if (downloadURL.contains(".gif")){
        type = ".gif";
        mime = "image/*";
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        folderName = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;
    }
    if (downloadURL.contains(".mp4") || downloadURL.contains(".avi")){
        type = ".mp4";
        mime = "video/*";
        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        folderName = Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES;
    }
    if (downloadURL.contains(".mp3")){
        type = ".mp3";
        mime = "audio/*";
        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        folderName = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC;
    }

            final String relativeLocation = folderName + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name);

        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + type);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mime); //Cannot be */*
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uriResolve = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

        try {

            if (uriResolve == null || uriResolve.getPath() == null) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
            }

            stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uriResolve);

            //This is 1GB change this depending on you requirements
            httpsReference.getBytes(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
            .addOnSuccessListener(bytes -> {
                try {

                    int bytesRead;

                    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                        stream.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
//FINISH

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    closeSession(resolver, uriResolve, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            closeSession(resolver, uriResolve, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);

        }
```

A better replacement if you want to monitor the download progress is by using `getStream()`, with this you can compute the downloaded bytes from total bytes to download.

```
httpsReference.getStream((state, inputStream) -> {

            long totalBytes = state.getTotalByteCount();
            long bytesDownloaded = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int size;

            while ((size = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                stream.write(buffer, 0, size);
                bytesDownloaded += size;
                showProgressNotification(bytesDownloaded, totalBytes, requestCode);
            }

            // Close the stream at the end of the Task
            inputStream.close();
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

        }).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            showDownloadFinishedNotification(downloadedFileUri, downloadURL, true, requestCode);
            //Mark task as complete so the progress download notification whether success of fail will become removable
            taskCompleted();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, false);
            resolver.update(uriResolve, contentValues, null, null);
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            Log.w(TAG, "download:FAILURE", e);

            try {
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(ioException);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);

            //Send failure
            showDownloadFinishedNotification(null, downloadURL, false, requestCode);

            //Mark task as complete
            taskCompleted();
        });
```

Check the sample project to learn more: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage